# Untar file in Python script with wildcard

Tags: python, unix, rar

I am trying in a Python script to import a tar.gz file from HDFS and then untar it. The file comes as follow **20160822073413-EoRcGvXMDIB5SVenEyD4pOEADPVPhPsg.tar.gz**, it  has always the same structure.

In my python script, I would like to copy it locally and the extract the file. I am using the following command to do this:

```
import subprocess
import os
import datetime
import time

today = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")

#Copy tar file from HDFS to local server
args = ["hadoop","fs","-copyToLocal", "/locationfile/" + today + "*"]

p=subprocess.Popen(args)

p.wait()

#Untar the CSV file 
args = ["tar","-xzvf",today + "*"]

p=subprocess.Popen(args)

p.wait()
```

The import works perfectly but I am not able to extract the file, I am getting the following error:

```
['tar', '-xzvf', '20160822*.tar']
tar (child): 20160822*.tar: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
put: `reportResults.csv': No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do what I needed, instead of using os command, I used python tar command and it works!

```
import tarfile
import glob

os.chdir("/folder_to_scan/")
for file in glob.glob("*.tar.gz"):
    print(file)

tar = tarfile.open(file)
tar.extractall()
```

Hope this help.

Regards
Majid

Answer (score 3):

Try with the `shell` option:

```
p=subprocess.Popen(args, shell=True)
```

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

> If shell is True, the specified command will be executed through the
>   shell. This can be useful if you are using Python primarily for the
>   enhanced control flow it offers over most system shells and still want
>   convenient access to other shell features such as shell pipes,
>   filename wildcards, environment variable expansion, and expansion of ~
>   to a user’s home directory.

And notice:

> However, note that Python itself offers implementations of many
>   shell-like features (in particular, glob, fnmatch, os.walk(),
>   os.path.expandvars(), os.path.expanduser(), and shutil).

Comment: Hi thanks. I am having now a different error:

    tar: You must specify one of the `-Acdtrux' or `--test-label'  options
    Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
 
Thank you

Comment: @Majid what's in your `today` variable when passing it to `Popen`?

Comment: it's the date of the day formatted as 20160822. I do that because I am receiving one file per day and I try to automate the process

Comment: Try printing `args` just before passing it to `Popen` so you can test with the same values in your terminal. The original issue is resolved, from now on is all on the shell side.

Comment: the print gives me ['tar', 'xvf ', '20160822*'] but with the same error tar: "You must specify ..."

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @martriay answer, you also got a typo - you wrote "20160822*.tar", while your file's pattern is "20160822*.tar.gz"

When applying `shell=True`, the command should be passed as a whole string (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)), like so:

```
p=subprocess.Popen('tar -xzvf 20160822*.tar.gz', shell=True)
```

If you don't need `p`, you can simply use [subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call):

```
subprocess.call('tar -xzvf 20160822*.tar.gz', shell=True)
```

**But** I suggest you use more standard libraries, like so:

```
import glob
import tarfile

today = "20160822"  # compute your common prefix here
target_dir = "/tmp"  # choose where ever you want to extract the content

for targz_file in glob.glob('%s*.tar.gz' % today):
    with tarfile.open(targz_file, 'r:gz') as opened_targz_file:
        opened_targz_file.extractall(target_dir)
```

Comment: Yes it's a typo, I tried to unzip and then unrar, but same first issue.